# Date listing between 2 dates (from -> to)

Tags: javascript, list, date

I want to list all dates between 2 dates like..

```
list_dates('06/27/2013','07/31/2013');
```

This function will return all dates between 06/27/2013 - 07/31/2013 in array like..

```
['06/27/2013','06/28/2013','06/29/2013','06/30/2013','07/01/2013','...so_on..','07/31/2013'];
```

This function will work in all cases , Like older to newer , newer to older , or same dates like..

```
list_dates('06/27/2013','07/31/2013');
list_dates('07/31/2013','06/27/2013');
list_dates('07/31/2013','07/31/2013');
```

I do like...

```
function list_dates(a,b) {
    var list = [];
    var a_date = new Date(a);
    var b_date = new Date(b);

    if         (a_date > b_date) {

    } else if  (a_date < b_date) {

    } else {
        list.push(a);
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/fSGQ6/

But how to get dates between 2 dates ?

Comment: Start with the smaller date, push it then [add a day to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime-using-javascript). If it's still less than or equal to the second date (and this might be tricky if one has a time component) then repeat.

Comment: _"But how to get dates between 2 dates ?"_ - in a loop, add 1 day to/subtract 1 day from your current date, and break it of if it's the same date as your end date.

Comment: mozilla will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: PS: You can add/subtract a day to/from a Date object by using `setDate` - it will automatically take care of changing the month as well if you go past the last or before the first of a month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
list_dates('11/27/2013', '12/31/2013');
list_dates('03/21/2013', '02/14/2013');
list_dates('07/31/2013', '07/31/2013');

function list_dates(a, b) {
    var list = [];
    var a_date = new Date(a);
    var b_date = new Date(b);

    if (a_date > b_date) {
        while (a_date >= b_date) {

            var date_format = ('0' + (b_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + b_date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + b_date.getFullYear();
            list.push(date_format);
            b_date = new Date(b_date.setDate(b_date.getDate() + 1));
        }
    } else if (a_date < b_date) {
        while (b_date >= a_date) {

            var date_format = ('0' + (a_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + a_date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + a_date.getFullYear();
            list.push(date_format);
            a_date = new Date(a_date.setDate(a_date.getDate() + 1));
        }
    } else {
        list.push(a);
    }

    console.log(list);
}
```

**UPDATE: as poster requirement**

Comment: Any easier way to covert to 'mm/dd/yyyy' format than `.getDate()` `.getMonth() + 1` `getFullYear()` ?

Comment: I guess no, but you can use a third-party library , such as: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Can you check my updated yours ? http://jsfiddle.net/fSGQ6/2/ (Added zero padding , Added from&to ) , If you are agree so update your answer pls

Comment: but mine is more elegant, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

```
var start = new Date(2013,06,27);
var end = new Date(2013,07,31);
var result =[];
var loop = true;

while(loop){
  console.log(start.toISOString);
  result.push(start);

  start.setDate(start.getDate()+1)
  if(start>end){
    loop = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.prototype.getShortDate = function () {
    // Do formatting of string here
    return (this.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + this.getDate() + "/" + this.getFullYear();
}

function list_dates(a, b) {

    var a_date = new Date(a),
        b_date = new Date(b),
        list = [a_date.getShortDate()],
        change = (a_date > b_date ? -1 : 1);

    while (a_date.getTime() != b_date.getTime()) {
        a_date.setDate(a_date.getDate() + change);
        list.push(a_date.getShortDate());
    }

    return list;
}
```